# Grails MissingMethodException trying to do operations over Multiple Datasources project (using Java Entity)

Tags: grails, groovy, datasource

I'm trying to use multiple datasources with Grails 2.2.1, but I ran into some problems accessing datasources others then the default. The issue is observed with POJO (not POGO) files.

The issue is when I try to invoke any persistence specific operation (like save(), list()) from a non default datasource an MissingMethodException is thrown (example follows). I do not have any idea of what gone wrong. I followed the grails tutorial (http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSourcesAndEnvironments).

```groovy
def entity = new MyEntity()
entity.myNonDefaultDatasource.save()
```

This issue can be achieved with the following coding flow:

Create a new Grails application

```
$ grails create-app TestMultiDB
```

Create new (package) for my entity class

```
$ mkdir src/java/testmultidb
```

Create entity code with JPA annotations

```
$ vim src/java/testmultidb/MyEntity.java
```

```java
package testmultidb;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    private long id;

    private String name;

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Edit Grails DataSource config file

```
$ vim grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy
```

```groovy
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}

// ***** Added DataSource
dataSource_a2 {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}

hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        }

        dataSource_a2 {
            dbCreate = "create-drop"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDbA2;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
            pooled = true
            properties {
               maxActive = -1
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
               numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
               testOnBorrow=true
               testWhileIdle=true
               testOnReturn=true
               validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Create hibernate cfg file for the second datasource

```
$ vim grails-app/conf/hibernate/a2_hibernate.cfg.xml
```

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
          '-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN'
          'http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd'>
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class='testmultidb.MyEntity'/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Create a controller

```
$ grails create-controller testmultidb.MultDataSources
```

Edit the controller

```
$ vim grails/controllers/testmultidb/MultDataSourcesController.groovy
```

```groovy
package testmultidb


import testmultidb.MyEntity

class MultDataSourcesController {

    def index() {

        def entity = new MyEntity()
        entity.id = 0
        entity.name = "Some name"

        MyEntity.a2.save()

        render "-"
    }
}
```

Run the application

```
$ grails run-app
```

Access

```
http://localhost:8080/TestMultiDB/multDataSources/index
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. `entity.save()` can be called from Java since the method is added to the domain class by an AST transform, so it's in the bytecode. But `entity.myNonDefaultDatasource.save()` is added to the metaclass since the datasources are dynamic. Java can't call methods or properties added to the metaclass.

You can call the methods, but you would need to have your Java code call non-dynamic helper methods in a Groovy class that then call the dynamic methods.

Comment: Tanks @BurtBeckwith. I understood, but do you have any example of how to do these helpers to use the datasources?